# Función PHP funciona en puerto 80 pero no en 443

Tags: php, http, apache2, https

**Datos**:

Apache: 2.2.1 escuchando por puerto 433, el 80 está deshabilitado.
PHP: 5.3.8
Plataforma: MediaWiki

A continuación expongo mi consulta por si algún semiDios es capaz de resolverla.

La función "renderlog" básicamente lo que hace es leer varias líneas de un fichero CSV y las muestra por pantalla en formato tabla "html" gracias a "strip_tags".

```
function wfshowlog() {
global $wgParser;
$wgParser->setHook('showlog', 'renderlog');
}

function renderlog($input) {
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$input = 'https://'.$domain.'/wiki/extensions/test.php';
$output = strip_tags(file_get_contents($input), '<table><td><tr><p>');
return $output;
}
```

Lo curioso del tema es que la función solo funciona si habilito el puerto 80 en Apache y cambio ***https*** por ***http*** en está línea:

```
$input = 'https://'.$domain.'/wiki/extensions/test.php';
```

Por más vueltas que le doy no soy capaz de dar con la tecla. Comentar que esa misma función funciona sin problemas en un entorno de las mismas características con excepción del servicio web que es IIS.

Gracias por adelantado !!!

Comment: Comprueba estas dos cosas: 1. Tu servidor tiene un certificado SSL válido y no caducado. 2. Tu php.ini tiene esto: `extension=php_openssl.dll` y  `allow_url_fopen = On`

Comment: Problema resuelto añadiendo **extension=php_openssl.dll** al fichero **php.ini**. Muchas gracias por la ayuda @ordago !!!

Comment: me alegro de que te haya servido. Si te animas, puedes hacer una respuesta indicando cómo lo has resuelto, así le puede servir a otra persona que esté en tu misma situación.

Answer (score 3):

El problema se resolvió añadiendo el texto: `extension=php_openssl.dll` en el fichero `php.ini`.

Gracias @ordago por la ayuda.